# C# trying to "get" from server

Tags: java, c#, tomcat, server

So I have a tomcat server that I can successfully send a query such as... `localhost:8080/AnarchyChatServer/AnarchyChatServlet?message=asdf&sendto=x&sendfrom=y`
This will run the doGet() in my tomcat server, I have nothing in doPost()
Which will simply return asdf x y in the response BODY as HTML. Now in my C# I am trying to build the query string and send the message as such...

```
 public string sendMessage(string message)
        {
            string url = "";
            string response = "No server response.";
            using (var wb = new WebClient())
            {
                UriBuilder baseUri = new UriBuilder("localhost:8080/AnarchyChatServer/AnarchyChatServlet");
                message = message.Replace("&", "(AMPERSAND)");
                message = message.Replace("?", "(QUESTIONMARK)");
                string queryToAppend = "message=" + message;

                if (baseUri.Query != null && baseUri.Query.Length > 1)
                    baseUri.Query = baseUri.Query.Substring(1) + "&" + queryToAppend;
                else
                    baseUri.Query = queryToAppend;

                url = baseUri.Uri.ToString();

                queryToAppend = "sendto=" + sending;

                if (baseUri.Query != null && baseUri.Query.Length > 1)
                    baseUri.Query = baseUri.Query.Substring(1) + "&" + queryToAppend;
                else
                    baseUri.Query = queryToAppend;

                url = baseUri.Uri.ToString();

                queryToAppend = "sentfrom=" + account[0];

                if (baseUri.Query != null && baseUri.Query.Length > 1)
                    baseUri.Query = baseUri.Query.Substring(1) + "&" + queryToAppend;
                else
                    baseUri.Query = queryToAppend;

                url = baseUri.Uri.ToString();

                try
                {
                    response = wb.DownloadString(baseUri.Uri);
                }
                catch (System.Net.WebException)
                {

                }
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Ignore the hideous code reuse and whatnot. Basically the query building seems to work correct as if I output "url" it will return the proper url with the query string, but the issue is is that when I print out response after the call has been made to the server it just says "No server response" as it was initialized at the top of the C# code. Basically I'm wondering how I can query the server. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: response = wb.DownloadString(baseUri.Uri);

does not set response equal to anything instead the System.Net.WebException seems to occur every time I make this call. The url is correct, so there must be something I am doing wrong with the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first problem is the lack of protocol in the Uri. Try this:

```
UriBuilder baseUri = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:8080/AnarchyChatServer/AnarchyChatServlet");
```

By the way... To debug these issues in the future, use:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{   <- breakpoint here

}
```

And examine `ex`. Or turn on breaking on thrown CLR exceptions in Visual Studio and debug the code (or just don't swallow the exception). Then you would see this:

[image]

Ignoring exceptions when debugging code is not a good idea in general...